# Change google sheets API call to batch

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-api

Working with google(and all) api calls for the first time, I'm continually hitting a rate limit threshold despite having limited my rate. How would I go about changing the following code to a batch format to avoid this?

```
#API Call Function
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=1, period=4.5)
def pull_sheet_data(SCOPE,SPREADSHEET_ID,DATA_TO_PULL):
    creds = gsheet_api_check(SCOPE)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        rows = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                  range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()
        data = rows.get('values')
        print("COMPLETE: Data copied")
        return data

#list files in the active brews folder
activebrews = drive.ListFile({'q':"'0BxU70FB_wb-Da0x5amtYbUkybXc' in parents"}).GetList()
tabs = ['Brew Log','Fermentation Log','Centrifuge Log']

brewsheetdict ={}
#Pulls data from the entire spreadsheet tab.

    
        
for i in activebrews:
    for j in tabs:
        #set spreadsheet parameters
        SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
        SPREADSHEET_ID = i['id']
        data = pull_sheet_data(SCOPE,SPREADSHEET_ID,j)
        dftitle = str(i['title'])
        dftab = str(j)
        dfname = dftitle+'_'+dftab
        brewsheetdict[dfname] = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `sheet.values().get()` is used for one Spreadsheet. So in your situation, when `time.sleep` is used in the loop, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I'm running this now and it seems to be working, adding a second of sleep time in the second loop is definitely overkill, but it's faster than iterating the code until hitting the rate limit over and over! thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In the current stage, there are no methods for achieving the batch request of multiple Google Spreadsheets in Sheets API. By this, I think that to use `time.sleep` might be suitable as a workaround. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tanaike's suggestion, I settled on the following solution. There's still remaining issues that I haven't resolved. Namely, the resultant API calls occured at a rate of .5/second, well below the published limit, but any faster would still result in rate limiting issues. Additionally, the code completed after executing the for loops on half of the list every time, requiring repeated executions. To work around the second problem, I included the indicated line to remove list items after they were iterated over, so re running the code began with the last incomplete record each time.

```
import time    
        
SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
recordcount=0
#if (current - start)/(recordcount) >= 1:
sleeptime=2.2
start=time.time()
for i in activebrews:
    SPREADSHEET_ID = i['id']
    for j in tabs:
        data = pull_sheet_data(SCOPE,SPREADSHEET_ID,j)
        dftitle = str(i['title'])
        dftab = str(j)
        dfname = dftitle+'_'+dftab
        brewsheetdict[dfname] = pd.DataFrame(data)
        recordcount+=1
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
        end=time.time()
        print(recordcount,dfname, (end-start)/recordcount)
    activebrews.remove(i)#remove list item after iterated over
    time.sleep(1)
 
brewsheetdata = open("brewsheetdata.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(brewsheetdict,brewsheetdata)
brewsheetdata.close()
```